# Variance of Fourth Sample Central Moment

Tags: variance, sample, moments, kurtosis

I am trying to derive a formula for the **variance of the fourth sample central moment** $m_4=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^4$ (where $X_i$ is the $i$th realization of a random variable, $\bar{X}$ the sample mean, and $n$ the sample size) in terms of population statistics (variance, kurtosis, etc.) and sample size.

I have found [a derivation of the variance of unbiased sample central moments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589865/variance-of-an-unbiased-estimator-of-central-moments), in particular, [derivations for the unbiased second central moment (variance)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/variance-of-sample-variance).
I would require a formula for the variance of the (biased) fourth sample central moment $m4$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In what sense? Do you want a formula? if you want numerical results, why not first calculate this quantity and then push it through a routine to calculate its variance.  In the second case the dimensions, units and magnitudes you're certain or at least likely to get raise problems of precision and interpretation. Interpreting instead a dimensionless equivalent, namely kurtosis, however defined, is tricky enough.

Comment: @NickCox, I have edited my post to clarify what I am looking for: a formula in the vein of those in the links I have provided.

Comment: As I recall, the formula you cite isn't an unbiased estimator even for the fourth central moment.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's why I wrote that I would require the formula for the variance of the biased fourth sample central moment $m_4$.

Comment: Sorry; I didn't read the second version closely enough.

Comment: The formula will depend on moments through the eighth, which depend on the underlying distribution.  Once you have seen it worked out for the variance of the first moment (mean) and second moment, all you have to do is go through the messy algebra: there are no new statistical ideas or insights.